# Oracle reports generator

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, jasper-reports, oracle-adf

I have a big code written in JSP and ADF which is related to a big database.
The client wants to make a report generator for him, So he can create reports with the columns he wants..
What's the best choice of an open source Library I can use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle **Apex**' Interactive Reports offer quite a lot for end users - your (I mean, developer's) query might look like`select * from ...`, and end user can then select columns he wants, group them, perform filters, aggregates, draw charts ... Really nice. Best of all: it is Oracle, and it is free.

Printing, though, isn't that simple, but - from my experience, users (for some reason) adore Excel. Regarding the fact that you can easily download report into Excel, that might suit their needs.